# How can i create a new XML parents for elements which are between two boundary elements

Tags: java, xml, xpath, jdom, jdom-2

I would like to create a new XML parents at the highest possible levels for elements which are between two boundary elements in the JDOM2 structure.
Practically there are no limitations to the placement of the `<start>` and `<stop>` elements.

Simplified example:

```
<root>
    <a>
        <ax>
            <start></start>
        </ax>
        <ay></ay>
        <az></az>
    </a>
    <b>
       <bx></bx>
    </b>
    <c>
        <cx></cx>
        <cy></cy>
        <cz>
            <cza></cza>
            <czb>
                <stop></stop>
            </czb>
        </cz>
    </c>
```

output:

```
<root>
    <a>
        <ax>
            <start></start>
        </ax>
        <added>
            <ay></ay>
            <az></az>
        </added>
    </a>
    <added>
        <b>
            <bx></bx>
        </b>
    </added>
    <c>
        <added>
            <cx></cx>
            <cy></cy>
        </added>
        <cz>
            <added>
                <cza></cza>
            </added>
            <czb>
                <stop></stop>
            </czb>
        </cz>
    </c>
```

Comment: That depends entirely on the code you're using? Which XML parser/serializer are you using? Where's your code so far?

Answer (score 1):

Here is some attempt in XQuery 3.1 (which you can run with Java using Saxon HE or BaseX, not sure whether for both over JDOM, I think Saxon supports that https://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation11/sourcedocs/tree-models/thirdparty.html) to identify and wrap the elements e.g.

```
declare namespace output = "http://www.w3.org/2010/xslt-xquery-serialization";

declare option output:method 'xml';
declare option output:indent 'yes';

declare function local:transform($node as node(), $siblings-to-be-wrapped as array(element()*)*) {
  typeswitch ($node)
    case document-node()
      return document { $node!node()!local:transform(., $siblings-to-be-wrapped) }
    case element()
      return 
        let $match := $siblings-to-be-wrapped[some $el in ?* satisfies $el is $node]
        return if ($node is $match?1)
               then <added>{$match}</added>
               else if (not(exists($match)))
               then element { node-name($node) } { $node!@*, $node!node()!local:transform(., $siblings-to-be-wrapped) }
               else ()
    default
      return $node
};

let $start-elements := //start,
    $stop-elements := //stop,
    $siblings-to-be-wrapped := for-each-pair(
      $start-elements, 
      $stop-elements, 
      function($s, $e) { 
        let $elements-to-be-wrapped := outermost(root($s)//*[. >> $s and . << $e][not(some $d in .//* satisfies ($d is $s or $d is $e))])
        for tumbling window $siblings in $elements-to-be-wrapped
        start $s when true()
        end next $n when not($s/.. is $n/..)
        return array { $siblings }
      }
    )
return
    local:transform(/, $siblings-to-be-wrapped)
```

Result is e.g.

```
<root>
   <a>
      <ax>
         <start/>
      </ax>
      <added>
         <ay/>
         <az/>
      </added>
   </a>
   <added>
      <b>
         <bx/>
      </b>
   </added>
   <c>
      <added>
         <cx/>
         <cy/>
      </added>
      <cz>
         <added>
            <cza/>
         </added>
         <czb>
            <stop/>
         </czb>
      </cz>
   </c>
</root>
```

Not well tested and currently, like in the shown input sample, looking only for element nodes to be wrapped, not expecting mixed contents with text nodes split by e.g. `<start/>` and `<stop/>`.

Minimal Saxon HE (used 12.3) code to run XQuery against an input file and output the result (for testing to System.out) is e.g.

```
import net.sf.saxon.s9api.*;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, SaxonApiException {
        Processor processor = new Processor();

        DocumentBuilder docBuilder = processor.newDocumentBuilder();

        XdmNode inputDoc = docBuilder.build(new File("sample1.xml"));

        XQueryCompiler xqueryCompiler = processor.newXQueryCompiler();

        XQueryExecutable xqueryExecutable = xqueryCompiler.compile(new File("wrap-siblings-between-milestones1.xq"));

        XQueryEvaluator xqueryEvaluator = xqueryExecutable.load();

        xqueryEvaluator.setContextItem(inputDoc);

        xqueryEvaluator.run(processor.newSerializer(System.out));
    }
}
```

Example online: https://github.com/martin-honnen/SaxonXQueryWrapSiblingsBetweenMileStones

To use JDOM2 with Saxon HE you need to download the source from https://github.com/Saxonica/Saxon-HE/tree/main/12/source and compile the `net.sf.saxon.option.jdom2` package into your Java project (and it seems comment out line 50 in JDOM2DocumentWrapper.java before you do that), then the code to run XQuery on the JDOM Document and return a new one is e.g.

```
import net.sf.saxon.option.jdom2.JDOM2ObjectModel;
import net.sf.saxon.s9api.*;
import org.jdom2.Document;
import org.jdom2.JDOMException;
import org.jdom2.input.SAXBuilder;
import org.jdom2.output.Format;
import org.jdom2.output.XMLOutputter;
import org.jdom2.transform.JDOMResult;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, SaxonApiException, JDOMException {
        Processor processor = new Processor();

        processor.getUnderlyingConfiguration().registerExternalObjectModel(new JDOM2ObjectModel());

        Document jdomDocument = new SAXBuilder().build(new File("sample1.xml"));

        DocumentBuilder docBuilder = processor.newDocumentBuilder();

        XdmNode inputDoc = docBuilder.wrap(jdomDocument);

        XQueryCompiler xqueryCompiler = processor.newXQueryCompiler();

        XQueryExecutable xqueryExecutable = xqueryCompiler.compile(new File("wrap-siblings-between-milestones1.xq"));

        XQueryEvaluator xqueryEvaluator = xqueryExecutable.load();

        xqueryEvaluator.setContextItem(inputDoc);

        JDOMResult jdomResult = new JDOMResult();

        xqueryEvaluator.run(new SAXDestination(jdomResult.getHandler()));

        Document resultDoc = jdomResult.getDocument();

        XMLOutputter xmlOutputter = new XMLOutputter(Format.getPrettyFormat());

        xmlOutputter.output(resultDoc, System.out);

    }
}
```

Example online: https://github.com/martin-honnen/SaxonXQueryWrapSiblingsBetweenMileStones/tree/UseJDOM